# Unable to install Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7 32GB

Tags: 64-bit, ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I bought a Nexus 7 tablet 32GB (flo) and found the information to install ubuntu-touch here: http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

I installed both phablet-tools and ubuntu-device-flash, my device gets correctly recognized in both adb and fastboot:

```
user@*****:~$ adb devices

List of devices attached 

0498b5**    device

user@*****:~$ adb reboot bootloader

user@*****:~$ fastboot devices

0498b5**    fastboot
```

This is the status reported by the bootloader after the unlock:

```
PRODUCT NAME - flo

VARIANT - flo 32G

HW VERSION - rev_e

BOOTLOADER VERSION - FLO-04.02

LOCK STATE - unlocked
```

I'm trying to install the Stable release with the command ubuntu-device-flash --channel=stable --bootstrap (as user) and this is what I get in my terminal:

```
user@*****:~$ ubuntu-device-flash --channel=stable --bootstrap

2014/07/09 21:02:00 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting

2014/07/09 21:02:00 Device is |flo|

2014/07/09 21:02:01 Flashing version 1 from stable channel and server +++++ to device flo

2014/07/09 21:02:01 ubuntu-touch/stable is a channel alias to stable

45.05 MB / 45.05 MB 
[=========================================================================================================================================================================] 100.00 
% 3.02 MB/s 

330.50 MB / 330.50 MB 
[=======================================================================================================================================================================] 100.00 % 
5.20 MB/s 

/home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/stable/flo/version-1.tar.xz

/home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz

/home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz

/home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-
771577bbf9ec25e5be7e513dd9e3e9b249a4fdb2664aef068c438fccb32cafbf.tar.xz

2014/07/09 21:03:21 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-
touch/stable/flo/version-1.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:03:21 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz 
to device

2014/07/09 21:03:21 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz 
to device

2014/07/09 21:03:21 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-
771577bbf9ec25e5be7e513dd9e3e9b249a4fdb2664aef068c438fccb32cafbf.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:03:21 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-
4cecf3052ae3d517869ca2ac632e7d49dfb0ef0b56cd6167754528dffbb9f5d7.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:03:21 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-
touch/stable/flo/version-1.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:03:21 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz 
to device

2014/07/09 21:03:21 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz 
to device

2014/07/09 21:03:33 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-
771577bbf9ec25e5be7e513dd9e3e9b249a4fdb2664aef068c438fccb32cafbf.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:04:17 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-
4cecf3052ae3d517869ca2ac632e7d49dfb0ef0b56cd6167754528dffbb9f5d7.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:04:17 Created ubuntu_command: 
/home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu_commands937086177

2014/07/09 21:04:17 Rebooting into recovery to flash
```

At this point my tablet (that was into the Ubuntu CWM-based recovery) reboots as expected but never gets into recovery, it wants to reboot normally and this gets stuck on a bootloop whith the ubuntu logo and the loading bar underneath.

The next step, reached this point, that I tried is the following:

Assigning execution permission to the script file:

```
user@*****:~$ chmod +x /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu_commands937086177
```

Rebooted the tablet manually into recovery and launched the command to run the script left behing by before:

```
user@*****:~$ ubuntu-device-flash --run-script=/home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu_commands937086177

2014/07/09 21:10:02 Expecting the device to expose an adb interface...

2014/07/09 21:10:02 Device is |flo|

2014/07/09 21:10:02 Flashing version 1 from ubuntu-touch/stable channel and server 
https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device flo

2014/07/09 21:10:02 ubuntu-touch/stable is a channel alias to ubuntu-touch/stable

2014/07/09 21:10:08 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-
touch/stable/flo/version-1.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:10:08 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-
771577bbf9ec25e5be7e513dd9e3e9b249a4fdb2664aef068c438fccb32cafbf.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:10:08 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-
4cecf3052ae3d517869ca2ac632e7d49dfb0ef0b56cd6167754528dffbb9f5d7.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:10:08 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz 
to device

2014/07/09 21:10:08 Start pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz 
to device

2014/07/09 21:10:08 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-
touch/stable/flo/version-1.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:10:08 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-master.tar.xz 
to device

2014/07/09 21:10:08 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/gpg/image-signing.tar.xz 
to device

2014/07/09 21:10:20 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/device-
771577bbf9ec25e5be7e513dd9e3e9b249a4fdb2664aef068c438fccb32cafbf.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:11:03 Done pushing /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/pool/ubuntu-
4cecf3052ae3d517869ca2ac632e7d49dfb0ef0b56cd6167754528dffbb9f5d7.tar.xz to device

2014/07/09 21:11:03 Created ubuntu_command: 
/home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu_commands420201674

2014/07/09 21:11:03 Preparing to run 
/home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu_commands937086177 to finish the flashing process

2014/07/09 21:11:03 fork/exec /home/user/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu_commands937086177: 
exec format error
```

Anybody can possibly help me getting this done? I don't reallu mind getting 13.x or 14.x on it as long as I can try it, really.

On my laptop, which is the machine I'm using to flash, I am running Ubuntu Saucy x86_64 and I'm afraid that my problem is due to the x86_64 architecture but I didn't find any information on internet about that...

Comment: I am using **Trusty, 64-bit**. I would instead try: **`ubuntu-device-flash --channel=ubuntu-touch/utopic --bootstrap`**